# Turning a File Array into a number of MenuItems

Tags: java, swt, switch-statement, menuitem, case-statement

I have written the following piece of code for a dropdown menu next a text box, *ProjectName*. When the button is pressed, a drop-down menu will open with a `MenuItem` for each file in a specified location. When the user presses the `MenuItem` the text in *ProjectName* will be changed to the name of the file.

```
static File file = new File("C:\\GradeCalc\\java\\saves\\");
static File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();

 Button btn = new Button(Name, SWT.FLAT|SWT.ARROW|SWT.DOWN);
      btn.setBounds(280, 50, 20, 20);
      btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                super.widgetSelected(e);

                Menu menu = new Menu(Save_Dialog, SWT.POP_UP);


                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                     switch(i) {
                      case 0:  MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
                            item1.setText(listOfFiles[0].getName());
                            item1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                    ProjectName.setText(listOfFiles[0].getName());
                                }});
                               break;
                      case 1:   MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
                            item2.setText(listOfFiles[1].getName());
                            item2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                    ProjectName.setText(listOfFiles[1].getName());
                                }});
                               break;
                      case 2:  MenuItem item3 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
                            item3.setText(listOfFiles[2].getName());
                            item3.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                    ProjectName.setText(listOfFiles[2].getName());
                                }});
                             break;
                      case 3:   MenuItem item4 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
                            item4.setText(listOfFiles[3].getName());
                            item4.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                    ProjectName.setText(listOfFiles[3].getName());
                                }});
                             break;
                      case 4:   MenuItem item5 = new MenuItem (menu, SWT.PUSH);
                            item5.setText(listOfFiles[4].getName());
                            item5.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                                    ProjectName.setText(listOfFiles[4].getName());
                                }});
                            break;
                     }



                }

                Point pt = Save_Dialog.getLocation();
                menu.setLocation(pt.x + 280, pt.y + 100);
                menu.setVisible(true);
            }});
```

The code is functioning as it should, but the number of `MenuItems` created is dependent upon the number of cases in the `switch` statement. If there are more files in the location then cases, the drop-down menu will not contain the names of all the files in the location.

So here is my question. How can I create a `MenuItem` for every file in the location without it being dependent on the number of cases in the `switch` statement or any other hard-coded value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you need a `switch` here, because you can just create the `MenuItem`s dynamically:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Menu bar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    shell.setMenuBar(bar);

    MenuItem fileItem = new MenuItem(bar, SWT.CASCADE);
    fileItem.setText("&File");
    Menu submenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
    fileItem.setMenu(submenu);

    File dir = new File("C:\\");

    for (File file : dir.listFiles())
    {
        if (file.isFile())
        {
            MenuItem item = new MenuItem(submenu, SWT.NONE);
            item.setText(file.getName());
        }
    }

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like this in my case:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked perfectly. I used a `switch` statement, because I wanted to create a MenuItem for each file in the `File[]` and was unsure how to create the MenuItems dynamically. I knew it could be done, but I was unsure how. Thank you once again for your assistance.